# Update data.table with another data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Assume that given `data.table` *da*, there is another `data.table`, *db* which has some column names equal to the column names of *da*. Some of those columns with equal names also have identical content. My question is how to replace those entries in `da` that have columns matching with `db` with content of `db`?

Much simpler put:

```r
require(data.table)
da <- data.table(a=1:10,b=10:1,c=LETTERS[1:10])

## All (a,b) pairs in db exist in da, but c is different.
db <- data.table(a=c(2,6,8),b=c(9,5,3),c=c('x','y','z')) 

## Data table dx will have c-column values of  db$c where (a,b) matches between da and db.
dx <- db[da,.(a,b,c=fifelse(is.na(c),i.c,c),on=c('a','b')]
```

Output

```r
> dx
     a  b c
 1:  1 10 A
 2:  2  9 x
 3:  3  8 C
 4:  4  7 D
 5:  5  6 E
 6:  6  5 y
 7:  7  4 G
 8:  8  3 z
 9:  9  2 I
10: 10  1 J
> da
     a  b c
 1:  1 10 A
 2:  2  9 B
 3:  3  8 C
 4:  4  7 D
 5:  5  6 E
 6:  6  5 F
 7:  7  4 G
 8:  8  3 H
 9:  9  2 I
10: 10  1 J
> db
   a b c
1: 2 9 x
2: 6 5 y
3: 8 3 z
> dx
     a  b c
 1:  1 10 A
 2:  2  9 x
 3:  3  8 C
 4:  4  7 D
 5:  5  6 E
 6:  6  5 y
 7:  7  4 G
 8:  8  3 z
 9:  9  2 I
10: 10  1 J
>
```

I know that the above achieves my goal, but it feels clumsy. Is there a built-in `data.table` way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it

```r
dx <- da[db,c:=i.c,on=c('a','b')]
```

Comment: As a sidenote, `data.table` has sometimes confusing notation. My first solution -- which is a join -- is of the form `db[da,...,on=...]`. My second solution, which is a sort of a subset and replace is `da[db,...,on=...]`.